# Java Applet Runtime error java.lang.ClassNotFoundException com.itextpdf.text.DocListener

Tags: java, applet

I have the following code that works fine as an application.  I am converting the code to an applet for web use. I am running this class statically from the main applet.

The code compiles without any errors. The code creates the output file. But when it attempts to create the Document it throws a runtime error java.lang.ClassNotFoundException com.itextpdf.text.DocListener

I have included the DocListener in the imports even though it is unnecessary. I have put all of the class files into a self signed jar file.  I have turned down the java security to allow self signed applets to run after prompting (test environment). The applet runs fine until I try to create the PDF document then it generates the runtime error.

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.io.File;

import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocListener;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.Paragraph;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;
import com.itextpdf.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker;

public class WFRPPDFWrite {

public static void WritePDF() throws DocumentException, IOException {

    String htmltext = "<!DOCTYPE html><HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Test HTML</TITLE></HEAD><BODY></BODY></HTML>";
    System.out.println("HTML: " + htmltext);


    FileOutputStream PDFOut = null;

    try {

        System.out.println("Attempting to Write PDF");
        PDFOut = new FileOutputStream(new File("HTMLOut.pdf"));
    } catch (Exception  fio){
        fio.printStackTrace();
    }


    try {

        System.out.println("PDF Write: 2");
        Document doc = new Document();

    System.out.println("PDF Write: 3");
    PdfWriter.getInstance(doc,PDFOut);

    System.out.println("PDF Write: 4");

    doc.open();
    System.out.println("PDF Write: 6");

    HTMLWorker work = new HTMLWorker(doc);
    System.out.println("PDF Write: 7");
    work.parse(new StringReader(htmltext));
    System.out.println("PDF Write: 8");

    doc.close();

    } catch(Exception doce) {
        doce.printStackTrace();
    }


    System.out.println("PDF Write: 9");

    PDFOut.close();
}
}
```

Comment: If you have `itextpdf.jar` or something similar, you have to add it to publish, e.g:
<embed ... archive="applet.jar,itextpdf.jar"></embed>

Post code to show, how you append applet on page.

Comment: I added the itextpdf.jar to my archive attribute in the applet tag and the applet was able to create the pdf.  Thank you TomaszDa

Comment: I'll post my comment as an answer, so you can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to append your additional jar (`itextpdf.jar`) to your archive attribute in the applet tag like in an example above:

```
<applet ... archive="yourApplet.jar,itextpdf.jar,otherjar.jar" />
```